# How can I display a JS object, which I created with object creator, on my web page?

Tags: javascript, object, html, display

I have made an object creator:

```
function zawodnik(nr, last, nationality, club) {  
  this.nr = nr;  
  this.last = last;  
  this.nationality = nationality;  
  this.club = club;
}
```

and created some objects with this creator in my javascipt file like:

```
var kurek = new zawodnik(1, "Kurek", "Poland", "ASSECO Resovia Rzeszów");   
var jaeschke = new zawodnik(2, "Jaeschke", "United States", "ASSECO Resovia Rzeszów");   
var tichacek = new zawodnik(5, "Tichacek", "Poland", "ASSECO Resovia Rzeszów");
```

How can I display the values of these objects on my web page? When I add this code to my other JS functions, they stop working. I wrote something wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to display a JS object on your web page? If it's just for debugging, use `console.log()` to display it in the JS console, it doesn't need to be shown to users.

Comment: I want these data to be available for users. Users should be able to see each players data when they for example click a button that shows it. Maybe you know other way to display such data on a website?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.You may want this to display easily:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
[kurek,jaescke].forEach(function(el){
  document.body.innerHTML+="<br>"+Object.keys(el).map(key=>key+":"+el[key]+"<br>")+"<br>";
});
};
</script>
```

Code has to be run after your code...

Comment: Should I use it in my html file with <script> clause or js file and somehow launch it to the html? Because the first option does not work :/ or should I change something in the code to personalize it for my needs?

Comment: @KrzysztofGrabowski you may append it to *window.onload*